# error while loading DefaultFormats, Scala signature DefaultFormats has wrong version

Tags: json, scala, sbt, lift-json

I am trying to parse json using  lift-json. I am following this link: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-json-array-parser-parsing-example-lift-json. I am encountering the following error:

```
error while loading DefaultFormats, Scala signature DefaultFormats has wrong version
[error]  expected: 5.0
[error]  found: 4.1 in DefaultFormats.class
```

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Can you please provide your build definition ?

Answer (score 1):

This error appear due to using wrong version of lift-json. Use the correct version compatible with Scala version. The following dependency fixed the issue due to compatible version with Scala 2.11

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
      <artifactId>lift-json_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

I hope this helps anyone gets the same issue in the future.